# Select elements without any class

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I need to find, via jQuery selectors, all spans in a page that have no class.

Example:

```
<span class='Cool'>do not found me</span>
<span>me, me, take me please!!!</span>
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector) and the [attribute not selector `[att!=val]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector) to filter out elements with a non-empty `class` attribute:

```
$('span:not([class!=""])')
```

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/eRe5Y/2)

Note however that `[att!=val]` is a non-standard jQuery selector, which means the selector cannot be used in CSS or with `document.querySelectorAll()`. If you're like me, and you're a stickler for following the standards and so want to eschew non-standard jQuery selectors where possible, the following is a direct equivalent:

```
$('span:not([class]), span[class=""]')
```

This matches

- `span` elements that have *no* `class` attribute, and
- `span` elements that *do* have a `class` attribute, but only when the attribute value is empty.

In most cases, though, you should be able to get away with just the first portion:

```
$('span:not([class])')
```

You'll usually only find empty `class` attributes in markup generated by the application that's responsible for outputting it, or by developers who aren't paying attention.

Comment: Hi Bolclock! Not work for me! But instead this work very well: span:not([class])
Thank you for ur suggestion!!! I made it ;)

Comment: @PadovaBoy: How can my code not work for you? `[!=""]` has been around since the first version of jQuery.

Comment: i don't know...it simply not work...i use Firebug with FireFinder with FF version 3.6.13 under window7 to test the selector

Comment: @PadovaBoy: In any case, if `:not([class])` works, that's fine :)

Comment: yep! tnx to your suggestion i found my way! This is the important thing! many many tnx!
ps: in theory my way is a 'better way' because jquery should be test if the attribute is present (['class'] === undefined), in your code it test if is empty: 2 different thing!
pps: it's a my personal supposition!

Comment: @brass-kazoo: The CSS version of the first selector is a little different as there isn't a `[!=]` attribute selector; you'd use `span:not([class]), span[class=""]` instead. In most cases, though, you should be able to get away with `span:not([class])`. You'll usually only find empty `class` attributes in markup generated by scripts or by people who aren't paying attention :)

Comment: The `span:not([class!=""])` selector mentioned above failed in IE11. Using `span:not([class]), span[class=""]` as suggested by @BoltClock gives cross browser success.

Comment: @gfullam: I opened my fiddle in IE11 and it seems to work fine. Either way I would definitely favor valid CSS alternatives over non-standard their jQuery counterparts where possible.

Comment: @BoltClock I didn't do the test in isolation; I put the code straight into a working project. It only failed in IE11 for me, but there was probably some interference with other libraries, etc.

Answer (score 4):

See this answer to do it with css only [Can I write a CSS selector selecting elements NOT having a certain class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110300/can-i-write-a-css-selector-selecting-elements-not-having-a-class/22183475#22183475)

```
:not([class])
```

Actually, this will select anything witch do not have a .class applied to it.

I gathered a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zrx4/) demo

html

```
<h2 class="fake-class">fake-class will be green</h2>
<h2 class="">empty class SHOULD be white</h2>
<h2>no class should be red</h2>
<h2 class="fake-clas2s">fake-class2 SHOULD be white</h2>
<h2 class="">empty class2 SHOULD be white</h2>
<h2>no class2 SHOULD be red</h2>
```

css

```
h2 {color:#fff}
:not([class]) {color:red;background-color:blue}
.fake-class {color:green}
```

Comment: OP asked for jquery selectors tho

Comment: @berbt  .. who needs to translate a .css-selector to a $('.css-selector') ?

Comment: Your solution is acceptable and used in the selected answer, but yes - since the author asked for a jQuery context, it would have been good to provide an answer in this context while explaining why it is also valid in css