# Is it possible to define in CSS NOT to apply style if element have certain class?

Tags: html, css

I have an application where styles are defined as

```
select { 
    border: 1px solid #6FA7D1; 
    outline:0; 
    height:25px; 
    padding-left: 5px; 
    font-family:Arial; 
    font-size:12px; 
    transition: all 0.8s; 
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; 
    border-top-left-radius: 5px; 
    }
```

so, every `<select></select>` will get the same style, which is expected, but, I'm using some third party plugins like jqGrid and I don't want to apply same style on for instance `<select>` rendered in jqGrid pager. This `<select>` has some class.
Is there some way to tell in CSS not to apply on DOM with certain class?

Please don't focus strictly on this `<select>` in jqGrid, I have more situations when I can use such exclusion.

Comment: Use select:not(.someclass):not(.anotherclass) { } /* someclass and anotherclass should be assigned to select element */

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector to prevent application under certain circumstances, e.g:

`:not(selector) select`

Where selector relates to either a jQGrid `id` or `class`

> The negation CSS pseudo-class, `:not(X)`, is a functional notation
>   taking a simple selector X as an argument. It matches an element that
>   is not represented by the argument. X must not contain another
>   negation selector.

This basically says target select elements which arent a child of `selector` (in this case jQGrid)

You can use `:not` to exclude any subset of matched elements.

```css
:not(div) > span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span>Make me red!</span>
<div><span>...but not me...</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/iaezzy/1s5g5mjn/

```
.element:not(.exclude) {
    background: green;
}
.exclude {
    background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about [Can I write a CSS selector selecting elements NOT having a certain class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110300/can-i-write-a-css-selector-selecting-elements-not-having-a-class) in CSS3?

```
select:not(.someClass) {
    /* Styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the only option would be to:

- Put the `<select>` styling into a class, e.g. `.select`, and add that `<select class="select">` to all elements that you want to be styled.
- Add a class, e.g. `select-jqGrid`, that overrides all default styling from the `select` and add that to all `<select>` elements inside the jqGrid.