# Is there a way to assert that an element does not have a class?

Tags: class, groovy, selector, geb, isenabled

I want to create a selector that will check that a specific element does not have a class at all.

I have this selector (Groovy) ->

```
selector = $('span', text: 'Walrus').parent().children("h5", class: notContains("disabled"))
```

This won't work because It's expecting the element to have a class, and for the class to not be 'disabled'.

Not looking for workaround answers, just curious if there's any way to do this in any language.

Comment: May be with  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110300/can-i-write-a-css-selector-selecting-elements-not-having-a-certain-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try selecting the h5 regardless of its class and then follow it up with an exclusion of all h5.disabled.

```
selector = $('span', text: 'Walrus').parent().children("h5").not("h5.disabled")
```

This would check for the specific scenario of a h5 with no .disabled, regardless of whether the element looks like `<h5 class="">` or `<h5>` or `<h5 class="other classes">`

However if you want to check that the element *does not* have a class attribute, that's another story.

You could also go something along the lines of:

```
selector = $('span', text: 'Walrus').parent().children("h5[class=''], h5:not([class])");
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the css3 selector not work?

```
$('span', text: 'Walrus').parent()
                         .children("h5:not([class])")
```