# How to select element that does not contain class that starts with a prefix

Tags: css

I am attempting to set a style for all the input elements that does not contain a class that begins with "border-radius":

```
input:not(class^="border-radius") {
```

This is not working. Any other ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I write a CSS selector selecting elements NOT having a certain class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110300/can-i-write-a-css-selector-selecting-elements-not-having-a-certain-class)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**Check Your Syntax**

Ensure that your class attribute selector is contained within square braces to avoid any syntax issues.:

```
input:not([class^="border-radius"]) {
   /* Your style here */
}
```

**Handling Multiple Classes**

Additionally, if you expect to contain multiple classes, you might want to consider using the contains selector `*=` instead as the previous approach will only work if the first class attribute starts with "border-radius" :

```
input:not([class*="border-radius"]) {
   /* Your style here */
}
```

**Examples**

This is an example demonstrating the starts-with `^=` selector.

[image]

```css
input { margin: 10px}

input:not([class^="border-radius"]) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input class='border-radius' />
<input class='normal' />
<input class='test border-radius' />
<input class='another-normal' />
<input class='border-radius-5' />
```

This is an example demonstrating the contains `*=` selector.

[image]

```css
input { margin: 10px}

input:not([class*="border-radius"]) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input class='border-radius' />
<input class='normal' />
<input class='test border-radius' />
<input class='another-normal' />
<input class='border-radius-5' />
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work. Not usually does but not in this case for me

Answer (score 5):

Try `input:not([class^="border-radius"])` instead. Attribute selectors are written inside square brackets `[]`.

```css
input:not([class^="border-radius"]) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="text" class='border-radius'>
<input type="text" class='border-radius-something'>
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you need to exclude a specific class, you can do it like this:

```css
input:not(.border-radius) {
  /* style here */
}
```

Comment: This does not work for all elements who contain a class that begins with `border-radius`

Comment: downvoting because this it doesn't address the question of "begins with"

Comment: Doesn't answer question, e.g. class="border-radius-custom"

Answer (score -1):

try this in javascript

```
this.el.on('click', 'ul.pagination li:not(.disabled,.active)', function ....
```

Comment: The user isn't asking for JS functionality, they are asking for CSS selection