# Exclude CSS class from inheriting

Tags: css

I have tried to search but am not sure if I am posing the question right.

I applied the following css to my site:

```
a[target='_blank']::after {
    content: '\29C9';
}
```

This means that all external links will get the icon attached to it. So far, so good, it works as expected.

There are some situations though where I do not want this to happen, like in social share buttons. How can I exclude some classes?

Like when the link appears in a div with class '`socialbutton`'?

PS I cannot add other style to these buttons (WordPress website and generated code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I write a CSS selector selecting elements NOT having a certain class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110300/can-i-write-a-css-selector-selecting-elements-not-having-a-certain-class)

Answer (score 3):

You can overwrite this css code by adding new css to the class.

Example you can overcome this:

```
a[target='_blank']::after {
    content: '\29C9';
}
```

By doing this:

```
.socialbutton::after {
    content: '\fff' !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was it. I modified it slightly to: '.social-icons a::after {
    content: '' !important;
}' and that did the trick. Thank you, @Smokinggunz !

Comment: If this worked please accept my answer. @MarjanCrabtree-theICTgirl

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:not()` selector:

```
a[target='_blank']:not(.social)::after {
    content: '\29C9';
}
```

Comment: That works only if the links themselves have that class, but the question was about them being in a _parent_ element with that class.

Comment: @CBroe Oops, I must haved missed that part, nevermind... :/