# Can I apply CSS only if an ancestor does not contain a certain class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

**Explanation:**

I'm not a CSS expert but my current attempt is this.

```
div:not(.classToBeAvoid) *{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Which in English I read as...

"Apply a red background to any element which does not have `<div class="classToBeAvoid">` as an ancestor".

But nonetheless, in my test, it doesn't seem to work like this.

**CodePen:**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eGVBVb

**Code:**

```
<div class="classToBeAvoid">
  <div>
    <p>
      Shouldn't be a red background on any element around here.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
 <p>
   Should be a red background
 </p>
</div>
```

---

```
div:not(.classToBeAvoid) *{
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: If you remove the second level of "div" in your first "block", it seems to work as you want it to.

Comment: So my code only works for direct descendants of `div`s? Can I make this apply to any descendant?

Comment: It actually reads as "Apply a red background to any element which has any `<div>` which does not `class="classToBeAvoid"` as an ancestor".

Comment: I can actually see how that makes sense, Quentin. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Please look into this post [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110300/can-i-write-a-css-selector-selecting-elements-not-having-a-certain-class)

Comment: This will be difficult to accomplish in CSS if you have the p in each div nested to different depths. I would set the default background to red and then for ones that you want to avoid, use the class to determine a different background, like so: https://jsfiddle.net/td8b0r26/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS negation pseudo-class :not() for parent/ancestor elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084112/css-negation-pseudo-class-not-for-parent-ancestor-elements)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your interpretation is totally correct. You are applying a red background to any `<div>` that is not of class `classToBeAvoid`. Unfortunately this also applies to child `<div>`s, which is the reason for your first `<div>` to also be red (in fact your first parent `<div>` isn't red, but its child).

There are several ways to solve this issue (at least with some trade-offs).

---

#### 1. The general siblings selector `~`

You can use the [general siblings selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors), which will work in your case, because your `.classToBeAvoid` is before the following `<div>` elements.

```
div~:not(.classToBeAvoid)
```

```css
div~:not(.classToBeAvoid) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="classToBeAvoid">
  <div>
    <p>
      Shouldn't be a red background on any element around here.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>


<div>
  <p>
    Should be a red background
  </p>
</div>
```

---

#### 2. No nesting

If thats not always the case (which I assume), one way would be to remove your `<div>` nesting to make it work.

```css
div:not(.classToBeAvoid) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="classToBeAvoid">
  <p>
    Shouldn't be a red background on any element around here.
  </p>
</div>


<div>
  <p>
    Should be a red background
  </p>
</div>
```

---

#### 3. Additional class

If you don't want to remove your `<div>` nesting either, you can apply classes to the top level `<div>`s and use these for the selector, i.e.:

```
.chosen:not(.classToBeAvoid)
```

```css
.chosen:not(.classToBeAvoid) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="chosen classToBeAvoid">
  <div>
    <p>
      Shouldn't be a red background on any element around here.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="chosen">
  <p>
    Should be a red background
  </p>
</div>
```

---

#### 4. Direct child selector `>`

If you also don't want to give every top level `<div>` an additional class, you can use the parent with the [direct child selector `>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors):

```
body>div:not(.classToBeAvoid)
```

```css
body>div:not(.classToBeAvoid) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="classToBeAvoid">
  <div>
    <p>
      Shouldn't be a red background on any element around here.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>


<div>
  <p>
    Should be a red background
  </p>
</div>
```

---

#### 5. Inheritance

Furthermore you can use your selector `div:not(.classToBeAvoid)` as you already did and in addition make sure, that child `<div>`s inherit the behaviour of `.classToBeAvoid`:

```
.classToBeAvoid div {
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

```css
div:not(.classToBeAvoid) {
  background-color: red;
}
.classToBeAvoid div {
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="classToBeAvoid">
  <div>
    <p>
      Shouldn't be a red background on any element around here.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>


<div>
  <p>
    Should be a red background
  </p>
</div>
```

---

4. or 5. are what I would prefer in your case.