# CSS selector but not when another class is present

Tags: css, css-selectors

How does one select the class `jdgm-paginate__page` unless `jdgm-paginate__next-page` is also applied to the element?

`<a class="jdgm-paginate__page " data-page="2">2</a>
<a class="jdgm-paginate__page jdgm-paginate__next-page" data-page="2"></a>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I write a CSS selector selecting elements NOT having a certain class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110300/can-i-write-a-css-selector-selecting-elements-not-having-a-certain-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [**`:not()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class:

```css
.jdgm-paginate__page:not(.jdgm-paginate__next-page):not(.jdgm-paginate__last-page) {
  color: red;
}

a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a class="jdgm-paginate__page " data-page="2">select</a>
<a class="jdgm-paginate__page jdgm-paginate__next-page" data-page="2">don't select next</a>
<a class="jdgm-paginate__page jdgm-paginate__last-page" data-page="2">don't select last</a>
```

Comment: How about if I also had the class .jdgm-paginate__last-page?

Comment: How should it behave with .jdgm-paginate__last-page?

Comment: Not select either .jdgm-paginate__next-page or .jdgm-paginate__last-page. Only .jdgm-paginate

Comment: You can add multiple `:not()` statements. See updated example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS :not pseudo class. For example:

```
.jdgm-paginate__page {
  background: red;
}
```

This would make all elements with that class red regardless of additional classes.

```
.jdgm-paginate__page:not(.jdgm-paginate__next-page) {
  background: red;
}
```

All elements with class .jdgm-paginate__page but no with .jdgm-paginate__next-page will be red

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution, but you can also use attribute selector to select your specific element in case you don't know what are the other classes:

```css
[class="jdgm-paginate__page"] {
  color: red;
}

a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a class="jdgm-paginate__page" data-page="2">select</a>
<a class="jdgm-paginate__page jdgm-paginate__next-page" data-page="2">don't select next</a>
<a class="jdgm-paginate__page jdgm-paginate__last-page" data-page="2">don't select last</a>
```