# Is there away to select all siblings divs up to the next from a specific class?

Tags: html, css

Is there away to select all siblings until the next specific class `.parent`?

In our case we have a list of Divs and there is no hierarchic in the HTML, they are all on the same level. We don't have access to update the HTML structure.

```
<div class="parent"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="parent"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="parent"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="parent"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

For example would it be possible to select the parent and child and add a alternate colors?

Comment: Are you asking only for one specific subset of the divs? Or simply all divs without `.parent`?

Comment: Are you referring to divs without a class as a child?

Comment: you need select the divs, and check if have the attribute   `class = parent `

Comment: @BlackHole Please don't provide answers in comments. Comments are for clarification requests or suggestions to improve posts.

Comment: Closing as a dupe of what I think you're asking... if/when you return, if that's not what you're asking, please edit your question to clarify exactly what you mean.

Comment: @TylerH not sure it is about a parent selector, the question title is probably badly worded ;) since the op is not too sure about how to

Comment: Looking to implement alternative classes based on the parent child relationship. So all divs under the first parent should have a background and the next parent and child should have no background.

Comment: @TylerH i reopened the question and reworded the question title , to avoid mistaking a class named parent with an hypothetic parent tag  here ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr I wasn't confused about that. The question here and the dupe target both cover classes. The name of the class is irrelevant.

Comment: @TylerH , maybe, but there is no need to climb the html tree, css can do it without doing so

Comment: @G-Cyr Your comments aren't making any sense. OP appears to be wanting to select elements without the `.parent` class. The dupe target showed how to do that.

Comment: okay, if the dupe meets the requirement

Comment: @Levikay FYI in your current markup there are no parent-child relationships. They are all siblings. Did you mean for them to have parent-child relationships (e.g. nesting divs within .parent divs)?

Comment: @TylerH I think the OP want to select a `.parent` element and all the div below it until the next `.parent` element (they are calling them child) to obtain a selection of parent-child. Basically each `.parent` and only the div before reaching the next `.parent` in order to apply an alternate style to each group

Comment: @TemaniAfif It's still unclear what OP expects (hence my most recent comment). Just a good example of why we should always wait for clarity before answering questions (or reopening them) :-)

Comment: Duplicate of [Can I write a CSS selector selecting elements NOT having a certain class or attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110300/can-i-write-a-css-selector-selecting-elements-not-having-a-certain-class-or-attr)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `~` selector and the `:not()` selector , so only elements in between `.parent` can be restyled.

example

```css
.parent~div:not(.parent) {
  background:lightblue;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

/* for demo */
body {
  counter-reset: divs
}

div:before {
  counter-increment: divs;
  content: counter(divs)
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="parent"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="parent"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="parent"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

To alternate background-color each time a class .parent shows up, CSS will need extra selectors to overide the previous ones

example

```css
.parent {background:lightgreen;}
.parent~div:not(.parent), 
.parent~ div.parent  ~ div:not(.parent)  ~ div:not(.parent)
/* and so on if there is more to mind about */{
  background:lightblue;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
.parent~ div.parent  ~ div:not(.parent) ,
.parent~ div.parent  ~ div:not(.parent)  ~ div:not(.parent) ~div ~div:not(.parent)
/* and so on if there is more to mind about */{
  background:none
}





/* for demo */
body {
  counter-reset: divs
}


div:before {
  counter-increment: divs;
  content: counter(divs);
  padding:0 ;
  margin:0.25em;
  line-height:1.5;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:white;
  height:1.5em;
  width:1.5em;
  box-shadow:0 0 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="parent"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="parent"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="parent"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I need to group them so that i can apply alternative coloring. In your example, i would like to get 2, 3 4 to have a background but 6 with no background and again 8 and 9 with background.

Comment: @Levikay you will have to repeat the selector and increase its specifity to keep alternative coloring . https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MWWELZw  That's about what CSS can do here

Comment: btw the `.parent~div` part of the selector is unnecessary here. Simply `div:not(.parent)` or even `:not(.parent)` will work here given OP's code.