# Apply style to all elements except for a specific selector and its children

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to style all elements inside a class while excluding a specific one and it's children. I've made several attempts using the **:not()** selector but I could not achieve what I want. Any thoughts?

```
 <div class="orange">
  <div>text</div>
  <div>text</div>
  <div>text</div>
  <div>text</div>

  <div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li> li text 1</li>
      <li> li text 2 </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Here is the link with the html and the styles.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-p7krtp?file=style.scss

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I write a CSS selector selecting elements NOT having a certain class or attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110300/can-i-write-a-css-selector-selecting-elements-not-having-a-certain-class-or-attr)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ">" the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator):

```
.orange {
  > :not(.list){
    color: orange
  }
}
```

This selects all children of .orange that do not have the .list class.

Answer (score 0):

What best worked for me while trying to find a solution for this approach was trying it out in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dy9L8opg/27/). I find the accepted answer not exactly correct because the syntax should be:

```
.orange > :not(.list)
{
   background-color: orange;
}
```