# Exclude sub DIV from DOM in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, dom

I have two div. `<div class="card" id="openWebsite">` and sub div `<div class="card__btn">`

If someone clicks on my root div they will get redirected to `example.com` and when someone clicks sub div they are redirected to `example.com` & `example.net`, they are getting redirected two both links in two new tab.

I want, if someone clicks on root div they should get redirected to `example.com` and when someone clicks on sub div button they should only be redirected to `example.net` not `example.com`

how to exclude sub div `<div class="card__btn">` from javascript.

Code :

```js
const webPage = document.querySelectorAll("#openWebsite");
webPage.forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const site = e.getAttribute("data-site");
    window.open(site, "_blank") || window.location.replace(site);
  });
});
```

```css
.card {

background: blue;
height: 100px;
width: 500px;

}
```

```html
<div class="card" id="openWebsite" data-site="https://example.com">
    <div class="card__btn">
      <a href="https://example.net">
        Visit Site
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Already tried from [jQuery exclude elements with certain class in selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015103/jquery-exclude-elements-with-certain-class-in-selector) , https://api.jquery.com/not/ , [document.querySelector exclude part of DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61079016/document-queryselector-exclude-part-of-dom), https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp

```
document.querySelectorAll("#openWebsite").not(".card__btn");
```

and

```
document.querySelectorAll(".card").not(".card__btn");
```

and

```
document.querySelectorAll("#openWebsite:not('.card__btn')");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make you internal div position absolute then it will work the way you want.

Comment: I did in css and still not working,

Comment: replace the querySelectorAll with querySelector, try this out

Answer (score 0):

there
your code is absolutely fine, just that you used

```
querySelectorAll()
```

instead of

```
querySelector()
```

only, because you only have one id on your page with the id "openWebsite",

below is a suggestion I believe you can add to your css to make your project more visible

```
    .card {
       background: blue;
       height: 100px;
       width: 500px;
    }
    .card__btn {
       background-color: red;
       padding: 10px;
      }
    a {
       color: white;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Events bubble up the dom. When you click on the anchor it opens `example.net`.
Then it goes up the tree and your event handler is triggered, causing `example.com` to be opened.
To stop this you can use [`Event.stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation). That way, the event won't continue going up the tree.

Because stackoverflow doesn't allow new tabs to be opened, I have also created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lusc/gfeoLt0z/1/).

```js
const webPage = document.querySelectorAll("#openWebsite");
webPage.forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const site = e.getAttribute("data-site");
    window.open(site, "_blank") || window.location.replace(site);
  });
});

document.querySelector(".card__btn").addEventListener("click", event => {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.card {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" id="openWebsite" data-site="https://example.com">
  <div class="card__btn">
    <a href="https://example.net">
        Visit Site
      </a>
  </div>
</div>
```