# Can I write a CSS code for elements NOT having a certain class, but only style?

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I need to write css code for site built with elementor.

```
<p>
 <span style="color: #000000; font-family: Poppins;">
  <span style="font-size: 18.6667px;">
   Hi, <span style="color: #ff0000;">have a nice day!</span>
  </span>
 </span>
</p>
```

I need to make my black text white and I need to keep that red text red.

I know that I can use elementor to color it. But I need it do thought CSS for dark mode.

I tried:
`p span span { color: red !important; }`
But sometimes elementor do paragraph with black text in `p span span`, so whole paragraph is red.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I write a CSS selector selecting elements NOT having a certain class or attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110300/can-i-write-a-css-selector-selecting-elements-not-having-a-certain-class-or-attr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following to select only the text that has an inline style of #000000

```css
span[style="color: #000000"] {
  color: grey !important;
}
```

```html
<span style="color: #000000">First words</span>
<span style="color: #FF0000">Other words</span>
```

Comment: Thanks. I modified it a bit. I've added semicolon after color code and its working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

> ***Can I write a CSS code for elements NOT having a certain class, but
> only style?***

Yes you can. Here is a snippet based on your example.

```css
*[style] {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span style="color: #000000; font-family: Poppins;">
  <span style="font-size: 18.6667px;">
   Hi, <span style="color: #ff0000;">have a nice day!</span>
  </span>
  </span>
  <p class="lowercase">this is lowercase text</p>
</p>
```

To answering your comment, here is an example overriding all the elements' `CSS`, you can change it to match the result you want;

```css
*[style] {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
p span[style] {
  color: white !important;
  background: #000;
}
p span[style] span[style] {
  color: indigo !important;
  background: white;
}
p span[style] span[style] span[style]{
  color: darkgreen !important; // this has to be like that to override the style setting the text color to red.
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span style="color: #000000; font-family: Poppins;">
  this is white text
  <span style="font-size: 18.6667px;">
   Hi, <span style="color: #ff0000;">have a nice day!</span>
  </span>
  </span>
  <p class="lowercase">this is lowercase text</p>
</p>
```

Comment: I need to make only "have a nice day!" red. (And black text make white)

Comment: @Jarda_H i am a bit confused since the text is already red. It has `style="color: #ff0000"` so i edited my answer and write how to override this also. Unfortunately for elements that color setting exist in `style` attribute of the element, you will have to use `!important`.

Comment: Sorry I am bad at explaining :D But elementor is sometimes retarded so it generate more span or less. But i used code from other guy. Anyway thanks for help.