# Exclude all child elements inside of a specified parent element

Tags: css, frontend

I want to set some attributes on all text excluded text in `<nav>...</nav>`.

I know it can be done using `:not()` but it only applies on parent element, not on children within that parent.

Is it possible, to apply `:not()` on all children within parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help:

```
nav *:not(....)
```

The * is a wildcard selector.

Maybe this is interesting for you too: [Can I write a CSS selector selecting elements NOT having a certain class or attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110300/can-i-write-a-css-selector-selecting-elements-not-having-a-certain-class-or-attr/9110350)

Comment: Thank you, I used `body:not(nav) > ...` and it works now