# How to style a label without an ID or class associated with it?

Tags: css

I got a FluentForm form embedded in a wordpress page. I need to style one of the labels that don't have an ID or class nor can I add one. Is there a way to style what is marked in the screenshot below?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I write a CSS selector selecting elements NOT having a certain class or attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110300/can-i-write-a-css-selector-selecting-elements-not-having-a-certain-class-or-attr)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the label has a `for` attribute, you can use that in your selector.

```css
label[for="selector"] {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<label for="selector">Pick Me</label>
```

Comment: Thanks Paulie, this helped save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

You can select label with `label[for=ff_150_description_3]` and style it:

```css
label[for=ff_150_description_3] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label for="ff_150_description_3">aaa</label>
```