# How to target the whole body except for some classes ? :not no work ? Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to target everything in the body except 2 classes

```
body {
 background: gray;
}
```

What I am try:

```
body:not(.myCustomClassWhereIsBackgroundWhite)  {
     background: white;
}
```

My angular component Profile:

```
<div class="myCustomClassWhereIsBackgroundWhite"> 
 ...other context
 </div>
```

In this component is not affected background: white;

This is no work ?
Please provide me some solution ?
I want to some class to change and not be background gray

Comment: `body :not(.myCustomClassWhereIsBackgroundWhite)` - note the space

Comment: right now  background: gray; is not affected... weird

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I write a CSS selector selecting elements NOT having a certain class or attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110300/can-i-write-a-css-selector-selecting-elements-not-having-a-certain-class-or-attr)

Answer (score 1):

`body:not(.myCustomClassWhereIsBackgroundWhite)` targets `body` elements which donot have class `myCustomClassWhereIsBackgroundWhite`.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

If you want to look elements inside `body`, you have to add a space like.

`body :not(.myCustomClassWhereIsBackgroundWhite)`

```js
body {
  background: gray;
}

body :not(.myCustomClassWhereIsBackgroundWhite) {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="myCustomClassWhereIsBackgroundWhite">
  ...other context
</div>
<div>
  Some other element
</div>
```

Comment: NO work. Here is problaby problem with angular components,,

Comment: @Sosauls which version of angular are you using?

Comment: using angular  9 ivy

Comment: this is no work ..body :not(.myCustomClassWhereIsBackgroundWhite) {
  background: white;
} 

Right now all body is white ?

Comment: ohh, right now work but remember old values on all page. Example background is gray. I go to page where need to be white background and it work... but stay background white for others page...and when i refresh it be again good ?

Comment: Are you undarstand or i need to better explain ? in short. All pages are ok for me. I come to a page where there should be a gray background and it works. I go to another page where there should be no more gray background but the body remembers the old value ( css value)

Comment: @Sosauls you have to handle in the individual components then.

Comment: Probably but how ? What ?

Comment: friend here is problem body ... I am add new tag on some component but i need to change body ...not that component ...