# Playwright select element with strict class matching

Tags: playwright

How I can select element with Playwright framework with a strict class checking?
For example, I have multiple elements on a page:

```
<li class="target target--disabled"></li>
<li class="target target--disabled"></li>
<li class="target target--disabled"></li>
<li class="target target--disabled"></li>
<li class="target target--disabled"></li>
<li class="target"></li> // <-----want to target only this one
<li class="target"></li>
<li class="target"></li>
```

I tried:

```
const element = page.locator('.target').first()
```

but it also target disabled ones.

Comment: ```page.locator('[class="target"]')``` or `page.locator('.target:not(.target--disabled)')` 
are possible but there's probably a better way to select that if you don't mind providing more context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I write a CSS selector selecting elements NOT having a certain class or attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110300/can-i-write-a-css-selector-selecting-elements-not-having-a-certain-class-or-attr)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this selector:

```js
const element = page.locator('.target:not(.target--disabled)').first()
```