# How to use CSS universal selector, but exclude some class and its children

Tags: css

I have a CSS rule like this:
`* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`
But i want to exclude that rule and retain original browser css style on some element (example: div with class="exclude") and its children.

I've tried
`all: revert;`
But that'll erase all css include browser default, which i didn't wanted to.
Is this possible? If not, is there any way to rewrite the code to achieve same result?

Comment: You could possible construct something using `:is` and/or `:not` but I suspect it would be extremely complex and fragile. If the universal selector is causing you difficulties it's likely that you are using it the wrong way or you should avoid using it at all.

Comment: `.exclude { margin: initial; padding: initial; }`? But do pay attention to Paulie_D's comment.

Comment: Set margin&padding to initial value make them reset to 0 in my case. I just tried using *:not(.excluded) as Paulie_D comment, then add exclude class to every descendant element of target element, it did work. But i'm still looking for any "prettier" answer. I'm really appreciate your support

Comment: `*:not(.exclude, .exclude *)` should do the trick,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I write a CSS selector selecting elements NOT having a certain class or attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110300/can-i-write-a-css-selector-selecting-elements-not-having-a-certain-class-or-attr)