# How can I select all the DIV that do not have a class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, each

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select elements without any class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991576/select-elements-without-any-class)

Using `jQuery` I want to select all of the `fieldsets` that do not have any class in it.

This is my code:

```
<div>
  <fieldset>teste</fieldset>
  <fieldset class="teste">teste</fieldset>
  <fieldset>teste</fieldset>
  <fieldset class="teste">teste</fieldset>
  <fieldset class="teste">teste</fieldset>
  <fieldset class="teste">teste</fieldset>
  <fieldset>teste</fieldset>
  <fieldset class="teste">teste</fieldset>
  <fieldset class="teste">teste</fieldset>
  <fieldset class="teste2">teste</fieldset>
  <fieldset class="teste2">teste</fieldset>
  <fieldset>teste</fieldset>
  <fieldset class="teste">teste</fieldset>
  <fieldset class="teste">teste</fieldset>
</div>
```

This is my code:

**[Here is a jsFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/ignaciocorreia/UNyeQ/4/)**

Comment: Answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991576/select-elements-without-any-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

```
$('fieldset').not('.teste')
```

or

```
$('fieldset:not(.teste)')
```

Comment: I have differente name there. I have the test2 and teste3 :/

Comment: Do you want to select the fieldsets that don't have any class set at all, or the ones that don't have certain classses set?

Comment: :/ sorry mate you are correct!

Comment: $('fieldset').not('[class]')

Answer (score 2):

With a jQuery selector:

```
$('fieldset:not([class])');
```

or, with loops:

```
var elems = $('fieldset');
for (var i = 0, l = elems.length; i < l; i++){
    if ( elems.get(i).className == '' ){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter too:

```
var $fieldsetNoClass = $('fieldset').filter(':not([class])');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UNyeQ/5/

Or just:

```
$('fieldset').not('[class]');
```